# In Perl, how do I reference a value within a loop after I exited a loop still in another loop

Tags: perl

I've been working on this for days. So, my project is to work with some protein data bank files (*.ent) using perl. I have a whole huge directory full of them, and I need to calculate the distance between the atoms CD1 and OD2. If OD2 is not present, then I calculate the distance between atom CD1 and OE2. Never are both atoms present in the file. This isn't an issue for me now, as I can directly print out those values in each file within an if and an elsif condtional.

But when I exit that if/elsif conditional, the memory of those values in each file, goes away. Again, I've done a lot of hard work to open up a whole loop of files to print the solutions to for each file.

Essentially, in order to calculate the distance, I need to calculate the radial distance for two points: P(x1,y1,z1) and Q(x2,y2,z2), where point P is the x,y,z coordinates of CD1 atom, and point Q is the x,y,z distance of OD2 or OE2. But I called them alternatives to CD1 atom coordinates.

PQ distance = sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 + (z2 - z1)^2]

In order to deal with like 800 (*.ent) files, I used a foreach loop to iterative over all files in a directory, and a while loop to loop through them. There are several columns of the *.ent files are separated by variable amounts of white-space, so separated each line into an array based on those conditions, and the array was @fields, so $fields[2] is the counting from zero the third column of the .ent file being processed, or the 3rd column is the atom name.

---

From all that I've parsed my *.ent files this is all you see, though the files do have more information. I just separated each line which if it contained ATOM.

```
ATOM      1  CB  GLU A   9      53.764  15.456  11.540  1.00  0.00           C

ATOM      2  CG  GLU A   9      53.265  15.125  12.928  1.00  0.00           C

ATOM      3  CD  GLU A   9      54.264  15.606  13.972  1.00  0.00           C

ATOM      4  OE1 GLU A   9      55.435  15.909  13.653  1.00  0.00           O

ATOM      5  OE2 GLU A   9      53.831  15.724  15.123  1.00  0.00           O1-

ATOM      6  CB  TRP A  16      51.989  19.241  13.113  1.00  0.00           C

ATOM      7  CG  TRP A  16      53.254  19.906  13.560  1.00  0.00           C

ATOM      8  CD1 TRP A  16      54.518  19.371  13.545  1.00  0.00           C

ATOM      9  CD2 TRP A  16      53.380  21.238  14.053  1.00  0.00           C

...
```

There are more lines of ATOMS but this is all I need. 
-----------

\The first three columns containing decimals as you read the file right to left are the x-y-z coordinates. Starting counting from zero, column 2 is the atom name (this is very important to me as it's the basis of my calculation), and column three is an amino acid abbreviation for the two amino acids in my file. They are actually not important because the important atoms CD1, OD2, or OE2 are the only ones that matter, and they don't repeat repeat so I can't mix the atoms up, and I am referring to the right atoms in each residue.

My entire perl script to calculate the distance looks like this. It's a lot!

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use 5.010;
    use Math::Complex;

# This program will take all *.gjf files in a directory and calcualte the distance of OE2 of Glutamate to CD1 of Trypotphan,
# It will also calculate the distance of OD2 of Aspartate to CD1 of Trypotphan.

# Logic: If residue =~ Asp, then calculate distance of OD2 to CD1
# Logic: If residue =~ GLU, then calculte distance of OE2 to CD1. 

# 3D distance = sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 + (z2 - z1)^2]
# This is the formula for the distance between points (x1, y1, z1), and (x2, y2, z2) in three-dimmensional space, or in a sphere. 

# x1, y1, z1 = OD2 atom of Aspartate, or OE2 atom of Glutamate.
# x2, y2, z2 = CD1 atom of Tryptophan.


    print "Watch and Learn!\n"; # Because I'm a badass biological programmer solving a complex problem.  

    my @files = <*.ent>; # Save all the files in current directory as an array. 
    my $file_array; # This will be used to calculate how many PDB files were in the directory 

    foreach my $file (@files) # A foreach loop loops through all the PDB files in the directory individually. 
    {


    my ($base,$ext) = split (/\./,$file); # split the files along the period (.) to a base and extension. 
    print "filename is $file\n";
    print "basename = $base \n";
    print "extension = $ext \n";

    my $OUTFILE_CD1_Distance = join('_', $base, "CD1_dist"); # *_CD1_dist.ent denotes that this is the file of the distance solution to the this file.
       $OUTFILE_CD1_Distance = join('.', $OUTFILE_CD1_Distance, "txt"); # The PDB extension has to be added to the file. 

    open (my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file) # open a file to read from. # This is my ent file.  
    or die "Could not open file $file $!";
    open(my $Coordinates, '>', $OUTFILE_CD1_Distance)
    or die "Could not open file $OUTFILE_CD1_Distance $!"; \# open a file to write to. # Coordinates is for PDB coordinates. 

    my $counter; 
    $counter = 0; 
    while (my $line =<$fh>) # while loop goes through all the rows of the original PDB files till it reaches the end. 
    {
    chomp $line;    
    $counter++;

    if ($line =~ m/ATOM/)
    {
    #  print "$line\n";
     my  @fields = split(/\s+/, $line); 
     # save the fields 2,3, 6,7,8

     my $Atom = $fields[2];
     my $Residue = $fields[3];

     my $x_coordinate = $fields[6];
     my $y_coordinate = $fields[7];
     my $z_coordinate = $fields[8];

#        Now that everything is parsed, calculate the distance. 
#    my $delta_x = $x_CD1_coordinate - $x_alt_coordinate;
#    my $delta_x_squared = $delta_x * $delta_x;

#    my $delta_y = $y_CD1_coordinate - $y_alt_coordinate;
#    my $delta_y_squared = $delta_y * $delta_y;

#    my $delta_z = $z_CD1_coordinate - $z_alt_coordinate;
#    my $delta_z_squared = $delta_z * $delta_z; 

#    my $sum_of_squares_diff = $delta_x_squared + $delta_y_squared + $delta_z_squared;

#    my $CD1_distance = sqrt($sum_of_squares_diff);

     if ($fields[2] =~ m /CD1/)
     {
         my $x_CD1_coordinate = $x_coordinate;
         my $y_CD1_coordinate = $y_coordinate;
         my $z_CD1_coordinate = $z_coordinate;

         \# print "$x_CD1_coordinate";
        \#   print "$z_CD1_coordinate\n";
     }
     elsif ($fields[2] =~ m/OD2|OE2/)
     {
         my $x_alt_coordinate = $x_coordinate;
         my $y_alt_coordinate = $y_coordinate;
         my $z_alt_coordinate = $z_coordinate; 

     #    print "$x_alt_coordinate\n";
#        print "$x_coordinate";

     }
         print "\$x_CD1_coordinate\n";

#   my $x_coordinate = $ echo $line | awk '{print $3}';
#    print $x_coordinate; 
    }

    } # ending while loop

} #ending foreach loop 

    $file_array = scalar(@files);


    print "\nI just processed $file_array ent files for you ... Computing the distance from CD1\n";
```

End of script:

What my issue is that while I can issue print statements in the if ($field  conditionals) to print the the 6 variables that I need to calculate the equation of the line, and it will print exactly those values. But when I exit that if conditional and try to print one of those 6 variables which is inside the if-conditional, while I am out of the if-conditional it will not work.

Basically, the issue is that I'm in one room and my program is in another room when I try to execute the formula that I commented out in my program. But if I can only see the x,y,z coordinates for only one point when I am in the loop.

Do you understand my problem? Can you offer some suggestions?

Thank you!

---

Hey, you know 
you guys were right about the variable scope. I should have declared the my variables up higher up within the while loop of the program. I met with a colleague and we fixed the program!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Math::Complex;

# This program will take all *.gjf files in a directory and calcualte the distance of OE2 of Glutamate to CD1 of Trypotphan,
# It will also calculate the distance of OD2 of Aspartate to CD1 of Trypotphan.

# Logic: If residue =~ Asp, then calculate distance of OD2 to CD1
# Logic: If residue =~ GLU, then calculte distance of OE2 to CD1. 

# 3D distance = sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 + (z2 - z1)^2]
# This is the formula for the distance between points (x1, y1, z1), and (x2, y2, z2) in three-dimmensional space, or in a sphere. 

# x1, y1, z1 = OD2 atom of Aspartate, or OE2 atom of Glutamate.
# x2, y2, z2 = CD1 atom of Tryptophan.


print "Watch and Learn!\n"; # Because I'm a badass biological programmer solving a complex problem.  

my @files = <*.ent>; # Save all the files in current directory as an array. 
my $file_array; # This will be used to calculate how many PDB files were in the directory 

    foreach my $file (@files) # A foreach loop loops through all the PDB files in the directory individually. 
{


    my ($base,$ext) = split (/\./,$file); # split the files along the period (.) to a base and extension. 
    print "filename is $file\n";
    print "basename = $base \n";
    print "extension = $ext \n";

    my $OUTFILE_CD1_Distance = join('_', $base, "CD1_dist"); # *_CD1_dist.ent denotes that this is the file of the distance solution to the this file.
    $OUTFILE_CD1_Distance = join('.', $OUTFILE_CD1_Distance, "txt"); # The PDB extension has to be added to the file. 

    open (my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file) # open a file to read from. # This is my ent file.  
    or die "Could not open file $file $!";
    open(my $Coordinates, '>', $OUTFILE_CD1_Distance)
    or die "Could not open file $OUTFILE_CD1_Distance $!"; \# open a file to write to. # Coordinates is for PDB coordinates. 

    my $counter;
    $counter = 0;
    my ($x_CD1_coordinate, $y_CD1_coordinate, $z_CD1_coordinate);
    my ($x_alt_coordinate, $y_alt_coordinate, $z_alt_coordinate);
    while (my $line =<$fh>) # while loop goes through all the rows of the original PDB files till it reaches the end. 
    {
    chomp $line;    
    $counter++;

    if ($line =~ m/ATOM/)
    {
    #  print "$line\n";
    my  @fields = split(/\s+/, $line); 
     # save the fields 2,3, 6,7,8

    my $atom = $fields[2];
    my $residue = $fields[3];
    my $x_ref_CD1_coordinate;

    my $x_coordinate = $fields[6];
    my $y_coordinate = $fields[7];
    my $z_coordinate = $fields[8];

     if ($fields[2] =~ m/CD1/)
     {
          $x_CD1_coordinate = $x_coordinate;
          $y_CD1_coordinate = $y_coordinate;
          $z_CD1_coordinate = $z_coordinate;
     #my $x_ref_CD1_coordinate = \$x_CD1_coordinate; 

         # print "$x_CD1_coordinate";
     #   print "$z_CD1_coordinate\n";
     }
     elsif ($fields[2] =~ m/OD2|OE2/)
     {
          $x_alt_coordinate = $x_coordinate;
          $y_alt_coordinate = $y_coordinate;
          $z_alt_coordinate = $z_coordinate; 

     #    print "$x_alt_coordinate\n";
#        print "$x_coordinate";

     }

#    print ref $x_CD1_coordinate

#   my $x_coordinate = $ echo $line | awk '{print $3}';
#    print $x_coordinate; 
    }

    } # ending while loop
    print "This is my x CD1 $x_CD1_coordinate\n";
    print "This is my y alt $y_alt_coordinate\n";

#        Now that everything is parsed, calculate the distance.

    my $delta_x = $x_CD1_coordinate - $x_alt_coordinate;
    my $delta_x_squared = $delta_x * $delta_x;

    my $delta_y = $y_CD1_coordinate - $y_alt_coordinate;
    my $delta_y_squared = $delta_y * $delta_y;

    my $delta_z = $z_CD1_coordinate - $z_alt_coordinate;
    my $delta_z_squared = $delta_z * $delta_z; 

    my $sum_of_squares_diff = $delta_x_squared + $delta_y_squared + $delta_z_squared;

    my $CD1_distance = sqrt($sum_of_squares_diff);

    # Finally print the distance to the screen and also to files: 
    print "This is the distance $CD1_distance\n";
    print $Coordinates "$CD1_distance\n";

} #ending foreach loop 

$file_array = scalar(@files);


print "\nI just processed $file_array ent files for you ... Computing the distance from CD1\n";
```

I'm glad I was able to right a script to do this. I've read some Perl scripts to calculate the distance between residues, but the function calls made zero sense to me, so I'm glad I was able to write a program to calculate the distance between two atoms!

Comment: Variable scope is important. The `my` keyword declares variables that are lexically scoped, which means that they can't be accessed outside their block.

Comment: So should I locally scope them, or what?

Comment: You're the badass biological programmer. What do you think you should do?

Comment: Haha! I just write that to make me feel more accomplished. I am a little self-absorbed, but it keeps me motivated, sorry.

Comment: You've restricted their scope too much. You need to place their declarations such that they are visible to all code that uses them. Sounds like you want them outside the `while` loop.

Comment: Okay, I will see if that works.